# clear memory with variable

Tags: bash, unix

Currently I'm creating a little script in BASH that will ask the user to fill in a new IP-address, subnet and gateway. That input goes to a file which will be writen to /etc/network/interface..

I got the script working, but it isn't bullet proof.

When the user input, is not a number but an alphabetic character, It returns and the user needs to fill again a number.
When the user still uses a alphabetic character, the script continues, even though giving a error.

My code:

```
    echo "Fill in your IP"
    read NEW_IP

    oldIFS=$IFS
    IFS=.
    set -- $NEW_IP

    while [ $# -ne "4" ]; do  
      echo "Must have 4 parts"
        read NEW_IP
        set -- $NEW_IP 
    done

    for oct in $1 $2 $3 $4; do
      echo $oct | egrep "^[0-9]+$" >/dev/null 2>&1 
      while [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; do
          echo "$oct is not numeric. fill your IP in the correct format;"
        read NEW_IP
      set -- $NEW_IP 
    done
```

I'm new with bash, above I didn't make it by my self. I've found this script on the internet. The while and do, I made that by my self as a loop.
Everytime the user fills in a wrong number It must return untill the user filled in a correct format.

The real problem lies at the second half of the code. When I fill in a wrong IP like 10.10.10.a, I get the error like I want and I have to fill in for the second time my IP.
When I type 10.41.12.r, an error occured but this time, not complaining about the r at the end, but still complaining about the a which I inserted at the first. 10.41.12 will be checkt, but that last character is different.

I can imagine that everything will be stored in memory, but how do I clear that?
unset or $oct=
won't work

Hope that someone can help me with this. It's my first time programming, and this is giving me a headache

thanks.

Dave

Comment: that snippet is not the entire script so hard to comment on the bit that is not working - but from the looks of things you are reading in ip again and setting it

Comment: Do the test for numeric inside your first while loop.

Answer (score 1):

`for` does not evaluate the condition several times. It just runs 4 times, setting `$oct` to `$1` .. `$4`. If you try several times, your input will be accepted, even if not numeric. Moreover, you should check "Must have 4 parts" again after getting the input in the loop.

BTW, you should check that each `$oct <= 255`.

Comment: How do I need to evaluate the condition more? I can now fill in 2 times a wrong input, and the second time I'll get through

Comment: Use `while` instead of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated code is often bad. Better read the input at one place and go through the same tests everytime.

```
prompt="Fill in your IP"
while
    echo $prompt
    read NEW_IP
    IFS=.
    set -- $NEW_IP
    IFS=
    if [ $# -ne 4 ]
    then
        prompt="Must have 4 parts"
        continue
    fi
    for oct
    do  if [[ ! "$oct" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
        then
            prompt="$oct is not numeric. fill your IP in the correct format;"
            continue 2
        fi
        # You might add more checks here.
    done
do  break
done
```